# How to check correct font size?

Tags: font-sizes

I'm doing UX testing. Wondering is there any way (think of application or javascripts) that I can run on a page and check what the font size of a-tags, p-tags, etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firefox

Tools-> Web Developer -> inspect

IE

Tools -> F12 developers tools.

IE developer tool works pretty well in my opinion.

[image]

Comment: Chrome: Wrench icon -> Tools -> Developer Tools. Or Ctrl+Shft+I

Comment: Firebug is an extension for Firefox which works in a similar way. You can trace styles and change both CSS-rules and actual html-markup without making changes to your document.

Comment: @MarjanVenema F12 also works in Chrome as an alias to ctrl+shift+I

Comment: Also in Chrome: Right click -> Inspect Element

Answer (score 4):

Also there is a great tool called WhatFont: http://chengyinliu.com/whatfont.html
You can check which font is used on the page, its size and line-height.

Another one is Fount: https://fount.artequalswork.com/

Comment: Developer tools built-into browsers are more efficient than third-party websites.

Comment: Right, but I can figure out which font used on the page using WhatFont with less efforts over Safari developer tool.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test the css automatically, you can use Selenium: http://seleniumhq.org.
A short article about css testing with Selenium can be found here: http://ajaxian.com/archives/csstest.

Comment: Hi Frank welcome to UX.SE! The question was about finding out what is displayed not testing it against desired specs.